# Javascript - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I've been banging my head against the wall and cannot seem to find solution, checked other posts with same warning and no answer helped/could be applied on my problem. Basicly lots of small pics and one I click on also becomes big in another place.

Error is in line 53, aka last line.

```
var images = new Array();

var imageThumbs =   [
            {"src": "images/img01thumb.jpg",    "alt":"City of  DU", "title":"City"},
            {"src": "images/img02thumb.jpg",    "alt":"Some txt", "title":"Some txt"},
            {"src": "images/img03thumb.jpg",    "alt":"City of  DU", "title":"City"},
];

var bigImgHolder = document.createElement("div");
bigImgHolder.setAttribute("id", "bigImgHolder");
document.body.appendChild(bigImgHolder);

var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "images/img01.jpg");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Big Picture!");
elem.setAttribute("id", "bigImg");
document.getElementById("bigImgHolder").appendChild(elem);

var imgHolder = document.createElement("div");
imgHolder.setAttribute("id", "imgHolder");
document.body.appendChild(imgHolder);

var elem2;

for(var i = 0; i<imageThumbs.length; i++) {
    elem2 = document.createElement("img");
    elem2.setAttribute("src", imageThumbs[i].src);
    elem2.setAttribute("alt", imageThumbs[i].alt);
    elem2.setAttribute("class", "thumb");
    elem2.addEventListener("click", function(){
        changeMe(i+1);
    })
    document.getElementById("imgHolder").appendChild(elem2);
}


function preload() { 
    var path = "images/";
    for (var i = 1; i <= imageThumbs.length; i++) { 
        images[i] = new Image(); 
        if(i<10){
            images[i].src = path + "img0" + i + ".jpg";
        }
        else{
            images[i].src = path + "img" + i + ".jpg";
        } 
        window.alert("image " + i + " loaded");
    }

}

//swap images
function changeMe(index) {
    document.getElementById('bigImg').src = images[index].src;
}
```

Comment: where is the changeMe function?

Comment: `i` isn't what you want it to be when event actually occurs....it will be maximum since `for` loop will be long over and completed and there is no index that matches `i+1` at the end of array

Comment: Change `images` in `document.getElementById('bigImg').src = images[index].src;` to `imageThumbs`. Or maybe you just forgot to call the `preload` function.

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah I just realised that but now I'm struggling to find a good method to actually solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `changeMe` function parameter this way:

```
function changeMe(index) {
  document.getElementById('bigImg').src = images[index-1].src;
}
```

The reason behind this is, you might exceed the range, by sending an `i+1`, where the range of `i` is between `0` and `images.length - 1`, but when `i + 1` occurs, it becomes, `images.length`, which gives you `undefined`.

Comment: this will also fail when index is zero

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve 2 issues, a closure for `i` and also not to go past end of array and start back at beginning:

Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imageThumbs.length; i++) {
    // create closure using IIFE
    (function (i) {
        elem2 = document.createElement("img");
        elem2.setAttribute("src", imageThumbs[i].src);
        elem2.setAttribute("alt", imageThumbs[i].alt);
        elem2.setAttribute("class", "thumb");
        // make sure we don't overshoot array length
        var next = i + 1 < imageThumbs.length ? i + 1 : 0;
        elem2.addEventListener("click", function () {
            changeMe(next);
        });

        document.getElementById("imgHolder").appendChild(elem2);

    })(i);
}
```